# Como guardar datos con laravel y botman studio (API Telegram)

Tags: base-de-datos, heroku, telegram

estoy desarrollando un botman para la api de telegram, tengo que guardar datos de acuerdo a las elecciones del usuario, pero no tengo muy en claro como se debe hacer ya que estoy usando Botman Studio para desarrollar el bot.

El orden es:

La aplicación pregunta algo al usuario, el usuario responde y esa respuesta es guardada en la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi archivo localizado en routes\botman.php funciona bien con la conexión a la base de datos, migraciones, seeders, clases, conversations etc.

Solo quiero una idea de como guardar la información que recibo, tengo entendido que la función "answer" es lo que se debe tomar como valor para guardar la información pero en las clases no me toma la consulta.

Si mi mensaje es confuso diganme, no soy buena explicando, gracias :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontre la solucion, solo tenia que utilizar la clase Conversations, como ven se recibe la respuesta del usuario y la cachamos con "getText();"

```html
<?php

namespace App\Conversations;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Incoming\Answer;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Outgoing\Question;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Outgoing\Actions\Button;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Conversations\Conversation;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Cable;


class Compatibility extends Conversation
{

  public function findCompatibility()
  {

      $this->ask('Ingresa el modelo del producto:', function(Answer $answer) {

           $this->valueName = $answer->getText();
      
 $this->buscaConector = DB::table('conector') // Aquí va el nombre de la tabla, NO el campo.
              ->join('modelo', 'cable.id', '=', 'modelo.idcable')
              ->where([
                        ['modelo.description', 'ilike', $this->valueName],
                     ])
              ->select('conector.description')
              ->value('conector.description');

          if($this->buscaConector != ''){
              $this->say('El modelo es compatible con: ' .$this->buscaConector);
              return $this->bot->startConversation(new Back());
          }
              $this->say('Lo siento, no pude encontrar compatibilidad con los datos proporcionados');
              $this->say('Intentalo de nuevo, segurate de que sea el modelo y marca correcto ó pulsa /Salir para regresar al menu');
              $this->findCompatibility();

        });

}
```

Dejo el codigo por si alguien lo necesita en un futuro, la base de datos debe estar ya creada, crear las migraciones, los modelos de tus tablas y en la conversación usar el modelo que necesitas para el insert.